# Sequelize query to find all records that fall between a date range and time range

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a column **time_scheduled** of type **Sequelize.DATE** which stores the scheduled time of **events**.

I am tying to create a Sequelize query where I can find all **events** that fall between a date range and time range. The SQL query for the same is below.

```
SELECT * FROM events where time_scheduled between '2021/10/01' and '2021/10/10' and time_scheduled::timestamp::time between '12:00' and '15:00';
```

Sample output for the same

| `id` | `time_scheduled` |
| --- | --- |
| `4d543320-4d23-46d2-8a54-fbb13a1251d0` | `2021-10-05 14:30:00+00` |
| `d6640e70-f873-436c-a59d-5a4c4fc655b7` | `2021-10-06 12:02:49.441+00` |
| `b11481b2-ffdd-413e-81af-f83df756bcc9` | `2021-10-06 13:55:36.62+00` |
| `53447517-f226-407f-94f4-63ddc8c17d9c` | `2021-10-07 13:59:48.123+00` |
| `f0344678-11eb-4422-9d23-43e8d5320f55` | `2021-10-07 14:14:13.647+00` |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Op.between` along with `Sequelize.where` and `Sequelize.cast` to achieve what you want:

```js
const records = await Events.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [{
      time_scheduled: {
        [Op.between]: ['2021/10/01', '2021/10/10']
      }
    }, 
    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col('time_scheduled'), 'time'), '>=', '12:00'),
    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col('time_scheduled'), 'time'), '<=', '15:00')
]
  }
});
```